# New products 404 after Store view delete

Tags: magento2, multistore

Magento 2.3.3

We were using 2 storeviews and now have deleted the extra one we added for testing. Now we have 1 store view and adding new products results in 404 page for the new product added. We have the below error in system.log

```
main.ERROR: The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again. [] []
```

Does anyone have experience with this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To confirm, after adding new products, you receive a 404?

Are you setting the store in your import?

OR are existing products, no longer showing?

If so I'd recommend exporting all products and then change the store view.

Comment: Hi, Adding products through magento admin panel. All our existing products are still showing fine. It's only on new products added that are showing 404

Comment: Store -> All stores -> Click on your store -> and make sure correct store view is set as default.

Comment: Hi, yeah 1 store showing with it set to default. I think it may be some database issue? Thanks